# Get args value from @before advice

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop

I already spend almost 1 week to understand this AOP thingy.

I aware that from the JoinPoint, we can pass the args to advice @AfterReturning something like that.

But, to get the value from @before advice back to JointPoint, it seems like impossible (based on my try and error).

Please help me to confirm, and if possible I would appreciate if you can show how it can be done.

Thank you.

Comment: Not really helpful when beginner asked a basic question, then you rate it down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I get you correctly, but if you are asking how to get information from a `@Before` advice back to the calling code, then that just won't work.

The `@Before`, `@After` and `@AfterThrowing` phases give you only a limited amount of control, by design. If you want to have complete control, you need to use an `@Around` advice.

I'll add more info if you add more detail to your question.

Comment: Thank you. Really appreciate it.